# on guildmemberadd multiplies more and more

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I am building a bot on discord with discord.js / node.js

I wanna welcome users and tell them what they need to do.
but i got this problem it duplicates and duplicates even more.

my code:

```
   //WELCOME MESSAGE//
    client.on("guildMemberAdd", async (member) => {

    console.log(`"${member.user.username}" has joined "${member.guild.name}" at ${new Date()}`);

    member.guild.channels.find(x => x.name === "welcome").send(`welcome ${member.user} Please watch your DM for a message from Auttaja and complete the Captcha verification to enter the main channels.`);
});
```

and in the beginning it puts it 1 time out like welcome  .... but after it was 2 times when 1 user joins, and then 3 times and even 4 times.

this is the output:

any one got any ideas or advices ?

Comment: The output:

https://ibb.co/gmbvjK

Answer (score 0):

- You can just add a global Boolean variable that changes its value inside `async (member) => { ...` and using `if statement` you can make sure it doesn't get triggered more than once